# Set CFileDialog selection programmatically

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I've derived a class from `CFileDialog` and added two custom check boxes, one of which is a "select all" check box. When the user checks the box, I would like the dialog to automatically select all of the files in the current directory, but can't find how to do this. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: File dialogs typically already have Select All option.

Comment: Have you tried setting the filename to `*.*`?

Comment: Set [`OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cfiledialog-class?view=vs-2019#remarks) flag then you can select all files via shortcut `ctrl+A` which you can synthesize using [`SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput)